# How do I get the first record from database in Rails and then load others with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a slider which contains many images. I want to load the first image and then, after the page loading is complete, load others with Ajax, one by one.

I want to run the slider if it has at least two images. If the third image is loaded, it appends to the others, and so on unless all images are loaded.

I use Rails 3.2 and jQuery. Does it make sense? How can I do this?

```
pages_controller.rb
def show
  @slider_items = @page.slider_items.where(:visible => true)
end

show.html.haml
%table.slider
  %tr
    - @slider_items.each do |item|
      %td.si
        .slider_item= image_tag(item.slider_image)
```

Comment: Is this for performance reasons,  you want to keep the site responsive in case there are a large number of images?  You could do it two ways,   #1 load one, show it in slider, then load all others and show, or #2, load one, show it in slider, load another show both in slider,  load a third, show all three in slider, etc...

Comment: never mind,  you explained what you want,  ONE by ONE.  I'll craft an answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to assume your slider is a javascript gizmo of some kind that requires a table structure.  So the first thing you have to figure out is how to insert rows into an existing table.

Assume you are generating the following HTML after your initial page load that only had ONE image:

```
<table id='slider'>
  <tr>
    <td class='si'>
      <img.... >
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to be able to, via javascript,  insert new rows into that table.  I'll have to assume you are using jquery at this point.  Here is some jquery:

```
$('#slider:last-child').append("<tr><td>Hi!</td></tr>");
```

If you cause that jquery to execute,  Your DOM would then contain:

```
<table id='slider'>
  <tr>
    <td class='si'>
      <img.... >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Hi!</td></tr>
</table>
```

execute the same javascript again, and then:

```
<table id='slider'>
  <tr>
    <td class='si'>
      <img.... >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Hi!</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hi!</td></tr>
</table>
```

That's a crucial bit of jquery code, but where does it go,  and how do you make it correct?

Well,  calling that jquery code needs to occur AFTER each AJAX call that get's the next image.  So the next problem you have to solve is how do you iterate over all the images, one at a time via AJAX?

That will involve a JavaScript variable to be maintained in the browser, a variable that is an index into all the images.  At the very least,  you'd have to capture the maximum number of images at page load.  You could do this:

show.html.erb:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var maximage = <%= @maximage %>;
    var curimage = 0;
  });   
</script>
```

In order for this to work,  you have to set @maximage.

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :prep_images , :only => [:show]
  def prep_images
    @maximage = @page.slider_items.length
  end
end
```

So when the dom ready event fires, thanks to the erb extension,  your HTML will contain a script section that contains:

```
var maximage = 12;
var curimage = 0;
```

Assuming there are 12 images.

At this point I have to mention namespace collision,  maximage could very well be variable used in other javascript libraries you use.  If you find that to be the case,  you'd have to address this,  but I'll assume there is no conflict.

OK, I've been constructing this post for a while now.  Let me know if you think I'm on the correct path,  and I'll fill in the remaining details.